# How to encapsulate handlers in an efficient manner in Python?

Tags: python

I am making up a handler to handle different types of data. Here is my current solution:

```
def get_handler_by_type(type):
    def handler_for_type_A:
        ...
        #code for processing data type A

    def handler_for_type_B:
        ...
        #code for processing data type B

    def handler_for_type_C:
        ...
        #code for processing data type C

    handler_map = {type_A: handler_for_type_A,
               type_B: handler_for_type_B,
               type_C: handler_for_type_C,
              }
    return handler_map(type)
```

However, this seems quite inefficient as I will call get_handler_by_type frequently and every time it gets called, the dictionary will be constructed again.

I know I could do this instead:

```
def handler_for_type_A:
    ...
    #code for processing data type A

def handler_for_type_B:
    ...
    #code for processing data type B

def handler_for_type_C:
    ...
    #code for processing data type C

handler_map = {type_A: handler_for_type_A,
                type_B: handler_for_type_B,
                type_C: handler_for_type_C,
            }

def get_handler_by_type(type, handler_map = handler_map):
    return handler_map(type)
```

But this is pretty ugly in my opinion. Because I have handler_for_type_Xs and handler_map that are polluting the global space. Is there a way of doing this both efficiently and elegantly?

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: What's wrong with having `handler_for_type_A` in the global namespace?

Comment: Unless there are a _lot_ of handlers, it's unlikely to be a hot spot

Comment: @WaleedKhan: As gnibbler pointed out, there will be a lot of handlers. Actually I am writing a program that parses Bluetooth Low Energy packets. There are different types of headers and each payload associated with a header must be processed differently. I do not want all these handlers appear in the global space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way will encapsulate it:

```
def _handler_helper():
   def fna():
      print "a" 
      pass

   def fnb():
      print "b" 
      pass

   m = {"a":fna,"b":fnb}
   return lambda x:m[x]

get_handler_by_type = _handler_helper()
```

You may want to use `def` if you want to have a docstring, but this works.

Another option might be to have a more OOP approach:

```
class _HandlerHelper:
   def fna(self):
       print 'a'

   def fnb(self):
       print 'b'

   # __call__ is a magic method which lets you treat the object as a function
   def __call__(self, fn):
       return getattr(self, 'fn' + fn)

get_handler_by_type = _HandlerHelper()
```

Comment: You could just `return m.get`

Comment: @gnibbler that will change the function signature.

Comment: @cwallnpoole I like this answer too. I am not used to think of returning a function to the caller. I will remember such tricks in future.

Comment: @cwallnpoole I revisited your answer today. I really appreciate this closure trick. gnibbler's answer below is good as I do not have to call `_handler_helper` and get a `get_handler_by_type` but every time `get_handler_by_type` is called, all those inner functions are evaluated again. May I ask if you know any book or source which details such tricks. I searched for 'closure, python performance tricks' or 'nested functions, efficiency' but I cannot get satisfactory answers. I read Learning Python and Python Essential Reference already. They mentioned closure but didn't talk much about it.

Comment: @foresightyj You shouldn't need to call it more than once.

Comment: @foresightyj If you are really worried about that (which you really shouldn't be, you're only evaluating the function every thing `_handler_helper` is called, which should only be once. Every other time they persist as part of the inner make-up of `get_handler_by_type`), I just provided an OOP version. Unless you are doing some incredibly low-level memory management (if so, why not use `C`?) the object's definition will not change. Of course, neither will the functions inside `get_handler_by_type`.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Sorry for the confusion. The `get_handler_by_type` I said I would be calling every time I need a handler for some type is the one proposed by gnibbler below, not the one you proposed. In your solution, all those small handlers are evaluated only once, which is very efficient. That is why I revisited your answer yesterday and became very fond of it. So I would like to know if there is a systematic description of such closure tricks. I know I might get to learn a lot of those tricks by learning a functional language.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to look the handler up dynamically (if you have a consistent naming convention)

```
return vars()['handler_for_'+type]
```

Another way is to store the map as an attribute of the function

```
def get_handler_by_type(type):
    def handler_for_type_A:
        ...
        #code for processing data type A

    def handler_for_type_B:
        ...
        #code for processing data type B

    def handler_for_type_C:
        ...
        #code for processing data type C

    if not hasattr(get_handler_by_type, 'handler_map'):
        get_handler_by_type.handler_map = {'type_A': handler_for_type_A,
               'type_B': handler_for_type_B,
               'type_C': handler_for_type_C,
              }

    return get_handler_by_type.handler_map[type]
```

Comment: This is truly elegant and efficiently. Thanks a lot.